# Read from a file and swap certain char in C++

Tags: c++, vector, replace, char, ifstream

In this function I need to replace all chars in a file that is inputted, e.g. an `a`, with another char inputted, e.g. an `i`. I have given it two shots but as I am new and it's way too late for my brain to even work any advice?

```
void swapping_letter()
{
ifstream inFile("decrypted.txt");   

char a;
char b;
string line;

if (inFile.is_open())
{
    while (!inFile.eof())
    {
        getline(inFile,line);
    }

    cout<<"What is the letter you want to replace?"<<endl;
    cin>>a;             
    cout<<"What is the letter you want to replace it with?"<<endl;
    cin>>b;

    replace(line.begin(),line.end(),a,b);


            inFile<<line


    inFile.close();

}
else
{
    cout<<"Please run the decrypt."<<endl;
}
}
```

or:

```
void swapping_letter()
{
ifstream inFile("decrypted.txt");   

char a;
char b;

if (inFile.is_open())
{
    const char EOL = '\n';                                          
    const char SPACE = ' ';

    cout<<"What is the letter you want to replace?"<<endl;
    cin>>a;             
    cout<<"What is the letter you want to replace it with?"<<endl;
    cin>>b;

    vector<char> fileChars;                                     
    while (inFile.good())                                            
    {
        char c;
        inFile.get(c);
        if (c != EOL && c != SPACE)                             
        {
            fileChars.push_back(c);
        }


        replace(fileChars.begin(),fileChars.end(),a,b);

        for(int i = 0; i < fileChars.size(); i++)
        {
            inFile<<fileChars[i];
        }
    }
}
else
{
    cout<<"Please run the decrypt."<<endl;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this is to read the original file, replace characters and write the output to a new file.

Then eventually when you are done probably overwrite the old file with the new.

Comment: your right i can replace the chars but when i try over writing the code mucks up, ill look into it thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Look closely at this code:

```
cout<<"What is the letter you want to replace?"<<endl;
cin>>a;             
cout<<"What is the letter you want to replace it with?"<<endl;
cin>>b;
```

It reads *two* characters, no more, no less. If you hit "a b enter", you will be okay, the enter will be unread, but that won't do any harm -- it will read the "a" and the "b" into the two variables. But if you hit "a enter b enter", it will read the "a" and the enter into the two variables!

Comment: really?! havent seen this before sorry i cant see but how can i resolve this?

Comment: Just type "a b enter" instead of "a enter b enter". Or change your code to read lines instead of characters.

Comment: my second shot at the code uses lines instead, yer? i cannot see how i can replace the a value with the b. or am i at the wrong end of the stick?

Comment: i need to keep a and b seperatly because other wise the question do not make any sense

Comment: thank you for ur input but i found the two inputs acted seperatly and didnt need to press a b enter

Answer (score 2):

I'd start with a relatively easy solution:

1. store the contents of the file in a `vector<char>` (watch out for large files)
2. traverse the contents of the vector and do the swap
3. overwrite the old file with the contents of the vector

Comment: can u spot where the error is in my code? coz ive been trying all night and its a no go, brain just wont work. is it the replace() coz that never works for me??

Comment: ur methos works best thanks but the problem was the overwriting of the file. thanks